# Remove the 'read more' and 'Add new comment' links on the home page

Tags: 7, navigation, nodes

How do you remove or modify the list of links shown after the content?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In your theme's template.php file, add this snippet:

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['is_front']) {
    unset($variables['content']['links']);
  }
}
```

Remember to clear the cache afterward. And replace THEMENAME with your actual theme.

Comment: @tim.plunkett I use zen theme when i insert your code inside my template.php  i got `server error` message.  what should i do? THanks,

Comment: Fixed the code.

Comment: @Berdir i did like this: `function STARTERKIT_preprocess_node(&$variables) { if ($variables['is_front']) { unset($variables['content']['links']); } }` and i cleared the cache. the page is come up but nothing is changed i still see the read more links. What should i do?

Comment: I'm no sure, try to see what value $variables['is_front'] has by printing it out, maybe you need a different condition

Comment: You could also comment out the if completely, then the links should be always be hidden. And of course, make sure that your function is actually called, did you clear the theme registry cache and so on?

Comment: `$variables['is_front']` is set by calling `drupal_is_front_page()`, you could always do `if (drupal_is_front_page())` as a sanity check in case `$variables['is_front']` doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the node template...

You can use node template overrides such as "node-fonts.tpl.php" where "fonts" is the name of the node type. You will copy "node.tpl.php" to make this then modify it to your liking. This template is found in "[SITE ROOT]/modules/node/". Copy this to your theme folder. When I do this I create a subfolder called "node" to help organize the theme overrides.

If you want an easier solution then I would use ConTemplate (otherwise known as Content Template). This will allow you to control this from the content type admin config (creates a template tab which has options for the teaser and the full node). This also provides details about the available variables and sample data from the last inserted node of the type you are looking at.