# About the "read more" link

Tags: 7, nodes

There are some [related](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3382/disable-read-more-link) [questions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3270/remove-links-read-more-and-add-new-comment-on-the-home) but they  are not very new, and  I'm not sure if I get it right. My question seems quite elementary.

Am I wrong in assuming the following basic fact? *In the standard default installation of Drupal 7, all articles show a "read more" link, even if there is actually no more text to show. And there is no simple way of changing that stupid behaviour.*

Please, tell me that I'm wrong.

Answer (score 2):

No, and yes - sort of, in order.

The teaser system assumes that there will always be more to read so if you choose to show the teaser, by default it will always have a 'read more' link.

You can, however turn off the link entirely quite easily.  Copy node.tpl.php from your main theme into your custom theme directory and comment out this part:

```
<?php print render($content['links']); ?>
```

If you only want to show a read-more link when there is more to read, you almost certainly need to build a custom module for that.  There's lots of good documentation on how to do that, but we can probably help with the specifics here once you have a framework going if that's what you decide to do.

Note that if you only want to change the behaviour for a particular content type, put some logic around the line instead of commenting it out, like this:

```
<?php if ($node->type != 'article'): ?>
  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

depending on the level of control you need, you could try the [Read More Control module](https://www.drupal.org/project/readmorecontrol):

> A module to control when the teaser Read More link appears in Drupal
>   7.
>
> There is no mechanism in core to decide if the read more link should
>   appear. This means that this link will always show no matter if there
>   is additional content to display. This module tries to overcome this
>   issue by allowing administrators to determine how to handle this link
>   in relation to both the content type and individual fields.
>
> The module allows you to add Read more links to other supported view
>   modes (RSS feed, Search results, etc) or even other supported entity
>   types. Particularly useful if you use panels or views and either
>   programmatically add additional view modes or use other contrib
>   modules to provide these.

Comment: Oh! Useful, much better than my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It still surprises me (perhaps I'm missing something?) that a module is needed, I'd say that that behaviour (show the "read more" link ONLY when there is more text) is totally expected/desired/standard in any blog/CMS.

Comment: it's a performance issue - by showing it all the time, the system doesn't need to check the length of the content against a defined standard to decide whether or not the read more is required, plus there may be options available only when viewing the full node rather than a teaser, even if the text itself is displayed complete in the teaser.